# How to reuse existing bitmap memory with Bitmap.createBitmap()

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to optimise my app memory usage by following the recommended practice of using `BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap`. What I want to do is slice a bitmap into stripes of height `stripeHeight` like this:

```
val stripeHeight = 10
val largeBitmap = // the original bitmap
val placeholder = // the bitmap object I want to re purpose for each stripe
val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
options.inBitmap = placeholder
val rows = largeBitmap.height / stripeHeight

for (i in 0 until rows) {
    //how can I set the options object into createBitmap?
    val stripe = Bitmap.createBitmap(largeBitmap, 0, i * stripeHeight, largeBitmap.width, stripeHeight)
    it.onNext(stripe)
}
```

The problem is `Bitmap.createBitmap` won't take a `BitmapFactory.Options` in its method signature. So I'm unsure how to tell android to allocate the new bitmap into the memory space of the previous one.

Comment: Are you sure that in the code you have right now some memory is allocated with every `createBitmap` call? `Bitmap.createBitmap` returns an immutable object - maybe it relies on existing memory?

Comment: did you manage to get this to work? did my answer help? i'm curious about the approach you went with

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be the following:

```
fun doBitmapProcessing() {

    val STRIPE_HEIGHT = 10
    //assuming your largeBitmap is a 320x240 ARGB8888 image
    val largeBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 240, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    //then allocate a buffer of size 320 * 240 * 4 (4 channels in an ARGB image) bytes
    val byteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(320 * 240 * 4)
    //create a bitmap of desired dimensions for the placeholder
    val placeholder: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, STRIPE_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    //copy the pixels from your large bitmap to a pre-allocated byte buffer
    largeBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
    //create an input stream from the pre-allocated buffer
    val inputStream: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(byteBuffer.array())
    //create the bitmap region decoder
    val bitmapRegionDecoder: BitmapRegionDecoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(inputStream, true)

    //create options, as before
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inBitmap = placeholder

    val rows = largeBitmap.height / STRIPE_HEIGHT
    for (i in 0 until rows) {
        //call decode stream on the input stream containing your data from *largeImage*, and the options
        //in which you specify that you want the memory of *placeholder* to be overwritten.
        val region: Rect = Rect(0, i * STRIPE_HEIGHT, largeBitmap.width, i * STRIPE_HEIGHT + STRIPE_HEIGHT)
        val stripe: Bitmap = bitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(region, options)
        it.onNext(stripe)
    }
}
```

Be sure to read the documentation of `BitmapFactory.Options#inBitmap` and use the result of `BitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(...)` instead of `placeholder` directly, since it is not guaranteed that the same memory location will be used.

There might be another solution through `Bitmap.getPixels(...)` & `Bitmap.setPixels`:

```
fun doBitmapProcessing2() {
    val STRIPE_HEIGHT = 10
    //assuming your largeBitmap is in ARGB 8888 format
    val largeBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 240, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    //create a bitmap of desired dimensions for the placeholder
    val placeholder: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, STRIPE_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    //create int pixel array in which the colors will be saved
    val pixels = IntArray(320 * STRIPE_HEIGHT * 4)

    val rows = largeBitmap.height / STRIPE_HEIGHT
    for (i in 0 until rows) {
        //save colors from desired location into the pixels array
        largeBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, 320, 0, i * STRIPE_HEIGHT, 320, STRIPE_HEIGHT)
        //write the colors saved into the array to the placeholder bitmap
        placeholder.setPixels(pixels, 0, 320, 0, 0, 320, STRIPE_HEIGHT)
        it.onNext(placeholder)
    }
}
```

Although I'm not so sure about the second one. ( haven't used `getPixels`/`setPixels` before)

Hope this helps